# How to highlight certain points in a regression

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I am running a regression and would like to highlight points that have extreme residual values.

I run the regression and add the residual column to my data frame then I set the data label I want to display in the dat$Outlier column and I set the color I want the the points to be in the dat$Color column.

Basically when you run this code I would like to display the text of the dat$Outlier as the data label and the have the points colored according to dat$color

```
time = as.POSIXct(c("2015-05-01 10:00:00","2015-05-01 10:05:00","2015-05-01 10:10:00","2015-05-01 10:15:00","2015-05-01 10:20:00"),"GMT")
s =rnorm(5)
m= rnorm(5)
dat =data.frame(t =time, s = s, m =m)
reg = lm(s~m)
dat$resid = resid(reg)
dat$Outlier = ifelse(dat$resid > sd(dat$resid)*1, as.character(dat$t), "") 
dat$Color = ifelse(dat$resid > sd(dat$resid)*1, "red", "black") 
dat
plot(s, m)
abline(reg)
```

For example If my dat data frame looks like this:

```
                    t          s           m      resid             Outlier Color
1 2015-05-01 10:00:00 -0.7141181 -0.54383561 -0.3645389                     black
2 2015-05-01 10:05:00 -1.7444731  0.09249989 -0.4226707                     black
3 2015-05-01 10:10:00 -1.1257465  0.12563139  0.2466758                     black
4 2015-05-01 10:15:00  0.6201680 -0.47515076  1.0746872 2015-05-01 10:15:00   red
5 2015-05-01 10:20:00 -0.7979108 -0.60000735 -0.5341534                     black
```

How do I make the row 4 show 2015-05-01 10:15:00 as the data label and have that point colored red?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `points` and `text`:

```
set.seed(1)

time = as.POSIXct(c("2015-05-01 10:00:00","2015-05-01 10:05:00","2015-05-01 10:10:00","2015-05-01 10:15:00","2015-05-01 10:20:00"),"GMT")
s =rnorm(5)
m= rnorm(5)
dat =data.frame(t =time, s = s, m =m)
reg = lm(s~m)
dat$resid = resid(reg)
dat$Outlier = ifelse(dat$resid > sd(dat$resid)*1, as.character(dat$t), "") 
dat$Color = ifelse(dat$resid > sd(dat$resid)*1, "red", "black") 
dat
plot(s, m, lwd=3)
abline(reg)

outlierRows <- which(dat$Outlier != "")

points(s[outlierRows],m[outlierRows],col="red",lwd=8)

text(s[outlierRows],m[outlierRows],
     labels=dat$Outlier[outlierRows],
     pos=1)
```

.

```
> dat
                    t          s          m       resid             Outlier
1 2015-05-01 10:00:00 -0.6264538 -0.8204684 -0.37276065                    
2 2015-05-01 10:05:00  0.1836433  0.4874291 -0.08680989                    
3 2015-05-01 10:10:00 -0.8356286  0.7383247 -1.20662950                    
4 2015-05-01 10:15:00  1.5952808  0.5757814  1.28941997 2015-05-01 10:15:00
5 2015-05-01 10:20:00  0.3295078 -0.3053884  0.37678008                    
  Color
1 black
2 black
3 black
4   red
5 black
>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = dat) +
    geom_point(aes(x = m, y = s, colour = Color)) +
    geom_abline(slope = reg$coefficients[[2]],
                intercept = reg$coefficients[[1]]) +
    geom_text(aes(label=Outlier, x = m, y = s)) +
    scale_color_identity(guide = "none")
```